# GridSearchCV and cross_val_score give different result in case of decision tree

Tags: python, classification

Using `GridSearchCV` `best_score_` and putting the `best_params_` from `GridSearchCV` to `cross_val_score`, Did i get different result. And this only happens in case of decision tree and random forest. While in case of "SVM", "KNN", "LR", result is same.
Here is code i am using:

```
def dtree_param_selection(X,y):
    #create a dictionary of all values we want to test
    param_grid = { 'criterion':['gini','entropy'],'max_features':["auto", "sqrt", "log2"],'max_depth': np.arange(2, 20)}
    # decision tree model
    dtree_model=DecisionTreeClassifier()
    #use gridsearch to test all values
    dtree_gscv = GridSearchCV(dtree_model, param_grid, cv=10)
    #fit model to data
    dtree_gscv.fit(X, y)
    print(dtree_gscv.best_score_)
    return dtree_gscv.best_params_

dtree_param_selection(good_feature,label)
```

`cross_val_score`:

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(dtree_gscv.best_params_)
acc = cross_val_score(clf,good_feature,label,cv=10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of tree based models, you should set the `random_state` parameter before training. It defaults to `None`. This would ensure the results are same.

From the [`documentation`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html):

> `random_state int or RandomState, default=None`
>
> If int, random_state is the seed used by the random number generator; If RandomState instance, random_state is the random number generator; If None, the random number generator is the RandomState instance used by np.random

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be due to the tree models used by GridSearchCV and cross_val_score being created with different random seeds. If that was the case you should be able to fix it by setting the random state explicitly. If you want to create `clf` from `GridSearchCV.best_params_`, then you should include `random_state` in the param grid, ie.:

```
...
param_grid = { 'random_state': [0], ... }
...
```

Another way to solve this problem would be if you use the GridSearchCV's best model directly in the cross val function to make sure you do not miss on any hyper-parameters:

```
acc = cross_val_score(dtree_gscv.best_model_, good_feature,label, cv=10)
```

Comment: can we apply grid search on random state to figure out the best value?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. You just need to assign an array of values to `random_state` in the param grid.